# Not able to select node for installation using Cloudera Manager

Tags: cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install CDH using cloudera manager 5.9. When it prompts for the hosts ip's it is able to scan that node, but afterwards the "Continue" button is disabled, please see the screen shot below:

[image]

Are there any reasons why the "Continue" button isn't enabled?

FYI: I am using Virtualbox and my VM is based on CentOS. I am able to reach to VM's IP address and from VM i am able to ping the Host IP address. (I have used Bridge network, so it is working fine).

Answer (score 1):

You already installed cloudera agent on this node (look at the column "managed", value is yes).
So, to use it, you must have a "already managed" tab in the higher part of your screen. If you click it you could choose your node as a host for your cluster.

If you're trying to complete a previously aborted installation, first click to the Cloudera logo of this page to go to the dashboard, and delete the cluster (Action -> Delete). Next connect to your host hadoopcluster and execute as root `yum remove cloudera-manager-agent`.

Rerun the wizard from your Cloudera Manager and you'll be able to select your hadoopcluster machine as a new host for your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Click the row 192.168.1.101 (to choose the row). The continue button should now become clickable.